# Two complex div tags on one line

Tags: css, html

I have created two buttons (more like stole them by following random tutorials)
http://cssdesk.com/bfwj9
What I would like to do is to have these two buttons side by side in this manner

Choose one: [play_button] [stop_button]

How do I go about ensuring that they end up on the same line?
I am a complete css newbie, but I learn by doing rather than reading all these complex css commands. So can someone help me please?

Comment: `<div style="float: left">`, or `<div style="display: inline-block">`.

Comment: make a DIV - put in display:inline-block; (this ensures that your elements are lined up together if the width and height are large enough)

Comment: In the future, please include all the HTML and CSS to demonstrate the problem (but without anything irrelevant) DIRECTLY in the question.

Comment: Sorry about that. I will keep that in mind for the next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#play_button
{
    float:left;
}

#stop_button
{
    float:left;
 }
```

Comment: As a bonus, what about other components being on the next line? Doing this ensured that ALL of my div tags are on the same line.

Comment: Following the float declaration, you need to "clear" to go back to the default behavior. On the next line add `<div style="clear:both;float:none"></div>`.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS:

```
#container_button { float: left; }
```

To add a little spacing inbetween them, you could even add `margin-right: 1em;`.

The reason this works is that your two buttons are [block level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements), and `float` allows them to sit side by each other.